Unity physics 2d ball not bouncing the same every time (paddle and ball game)
I am currently making a unity game for "paddle and ball", and the game is kind of a spinoff of the real version. The paddle bounces the ball up, and hits it in the direction of the paddle. Currently my game does work, and the paddle kind of rotates with its inertia and hits the ball in the direction it is turned in. If I let the ball bounce on the paddle without moving anything it bounces the same height every time (that's good), but if I swerve the paddle and hit it it bounces a LOT higher, and goes all over the place.

The physics mat "BallBounce" has 0 friction and 1 bounciness. I currently have no scripts for the ball.
This is an image of my 2d ball and it's sphere collider:


That is my paddle
https://academy.cs.cmu.edu/sharing/ivoryMonkey2038 is the project I made in python and it is the sort of physics I'm going for.
If you want to know, here is my code for my paddle movement (I'm pretty sure it's not affecting the ball other than the movement itself):
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class PaddleMove : MonoBehaviour
{
    private Rigidbody2D rb;

    void Start() 
    {
        rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
    }

    public Vector3 mousePos;

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        // Variables
        mousePos = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition);
        GameObject paddle = GameObject.FindWithTag("Player");
        float xVelocity = rb.velocity.x;
        float rotationAngle = xVelocity / -2.5f;

        mousePos.y = transform.position.y;

        Vector2 moveDirection = (mousePos - transform.position).normalized;
        rb.velocity = moveDirection * 50f;

        transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(0f, 0f, rotationAngle);
    }
}

